# structure expected on left side of . or .* but it is a structure

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, most-vexing-parse

I'm getting the compile error `structure required on left side of . or .*` on `chest.contents[0]`, but `chest` is a structure:

```
class Item {
public:
    int id;
    int dmg;
};

class Chest {
public:
    Item contents[10];
};

int main() 
{
    Chest chest();

    Item item = chest.contents[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You meant to say `chest` is an object, but that's still wrong.

Comment: @chris: He's using "structure" in the same sense the compiler error message is, meaning "an object which is an instance of a class type".  And yes, that assertion is wrong.

Comment: This error is so notorious that there is a tag for it... it is called the "Most Vexing Parse".

Comment: @BenVoigt, That's odd. I didn't see the exact error, but I've never heard an object called a structure, unless it's supposed to be a different meaning.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: This is closely related to most vexing parse, but not actually it.  Most vexing parse is: `T t(S());` where `S` and `T` are types and `S()` is intended to construct a temporary object to be passed to a converting constructor.  It's considerably more problematic than this because the fix is so subtle and often gets removed during code cleanup efforts.

Comment: @chris: For example, the explanation for [C2231](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2z7czs3.aspx).  To be pedantic, it should say "*the type of* the operand to the left", or "*an instance of* a class, structure, or union".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it isn't, it's a function that takes zero parameters.

To default-initialize a variable, use

```
Chest chest;
```

In C++11, this syntax can be used for value-initialization.

```
Chest chest{};
```

In C++03, that needs a complicated (because of many compiler bugs) workaround, which the Boost library thankfully has made easy to use:

```
boost::value_initialized<Chest> chest;
```

Comment: Also known as [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @Bitmask: It's not.  Did you read the comments under the question?  Or your link?

Comment: @BenVoigt: That rather depends how you quantify vexation. I'd say that before 2011 this was more vexing, since as you say it needed weird magic to resolve in general, rather than a simple pair of parentheses. These days, they're about as vexing as each other.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Now I did. As far as I am concerned this is the same phenomenon. Parentheses that were intended to denote the default constructor call were instead interpreted as parentheses around the (possibly empty) formal parameters in a function declaration.

Answer (score 6):

```
Chest chest();
```

Is not as you might believe, a call to the constructor

```
Chest::Chest();
```

But rather the declaration of a function.  The proper way to create your `chest` is

```
Chest chest;
```

It is only when you have defined constructors that takes arguments you should use the parenthesis.

```
string s;
string s2("Hello");
```